# Convert Select statement results into binary and insert into a varbinary column

Tags: sql-server

I am attempting to accomplish the following and 1) not sure if it can be done and 2) if it can I have no idea how!  I have tried a couple of approaches but no joy. FYI I am not a full time DBA....just have the task as part of my web dev job.

Using SQL Server 2008 R2 I have a table with a `varbinary` column that holds a `.csv` file. The current external process gets the results from a select statement, writes the results to disk, retrieves the file, and the writes it to the database column. What I am wondering is if the following is possible:

Within the stored procedure take the results from the select statement and insert them directly into the `varbinary` column via a `CONVERT` or ??. My goal is to eliminate the writing to disk portion and hopefully just have to run the procedure to get the data into the database.

Any assistance you could provide would be appreciated! Thanks in advance...

Comment: I think I understand you...does this accomplish what you want? `UPDATE tableA SET col1 = (SELECT CAST(col2 as varbinary) FROM tableB WHERE...) WHERE...`

Comment: Hmmm...close.  My select is something like SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table1.  This is returned to the calling client as a dataset, written to disk etc.  What I tried (and does not work!!) is 

UPDATE tableA SET binaryCol = (CAST(SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM tableb WHERE...) as varbinary) 

So really I am looking to convert the resulting record set to a binary and update the binary column.  FYI I sort of knew that would not work but thought I would try it anyway.  :)

Comment: Can you post all the queries you're currently using?

Comment: Why on earth are you storing CSV files which are simply the output from a query in a column within the database table?  I think we need to rethink the database design a bit.